# Active Second Order Low Pass Filter Does Not Give Desired Output

Tags: filter, low-pass

I am creating a second order low pass active filter, with a cutoff of 140kHz and unity gain.
[image: LPF]

However the filter does not give an output representative of a Low Pass Filter.
[image: Filter Response]
I dont know where i am going wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhvKlw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What op amp are you really using in your simulation?  The '741 needs more than 5 V across it to work properly.  And most of the performance values for the 741 are specified with supplies of +/- 15 V.

Comment: And the 741 doesn't have the gain vs frequency performance you need to implement a LPF with a 140 KHz cutoff freq.  Chose a better op amp and make sure you have the supply voltages set accordingly.

Comment: Check the dc levels at the nodes in your simulation. You will probably find that the op amp is not working with the power supply you have specified.

Comment: Remember that all 741 types have a large signal bandwidth of app. 10kHz only (due to the small slew rate)

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/610681/95619) (at least very similar)?

Answer (score 1):

The inputs are biased off with incorrect unipolar supplies for a 0Vdc signal.

The 741 is also wired with reverse power voltage.

Therefore -90 dB attenuation seems reasonable.

**Always be aware of the input type from datasheet** (NPN or PNP or Nch/Pch) and **Vcm range if it operates on unipolar supply ranges.**